# JS/HTML my form submit button isn't showing an error message when the form is incomplete

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

Only been studying a couple of months, trying to learn the basics. I have created a form, I have tried to input javascript to show an error message when the submit button is clicked, but there is incomplete information. I have only tested this on the user name field so far, but my message "Name is required" isn't showing when i click submit but leave the username empty.

I have followed this code from a youtube video, and as far as i can see it looks okay! i have put the js in a syntax validator too. I originally had the IDs on the divs and not the input tag, so changed this.

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name')

formZ.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  let messages = []
  if (name.value === '' || name.value == null) {
    messages.push('Name is required')
  }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    error.innerText = messages.join(', ')
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="errorMessage"> </div>

<form action="/" method="GET" id="formZ">
  <div id="form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" class="inputField" id="name">
    </div>
    <div id="submitArea">
      <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So what i'm aiming for is, a user tries to submit the form without filling in their name, an error message pops up to say "Name is required".

Comment: Add html5 form validator like required attribute for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the expected result because the name field is `required`, which means that if the field is left blank, no submission would happen.

Since the only checks you did on submit are that `name` is not empty or not null, and the browser automatically prevent the user from submitting the form when `name` is empty, you don't see the error message.

Iv'e added a condition for adding errors when the user enter the string `a`. Try to enter `a` and submit and you will see your expected result.

Plus in your code you are missing a few variables (`error` and `formZ`) so I've added them as well.

The way I see it there are 2 options for you:
1. Add different error cases, ones that don't check only empty values.
2. Don't use the `required` property.

Anyway I'm suggesting you to read about [form validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp), it might help you.

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name');
const error = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
const formZ = document.getElementById('formZ');

formZ.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

  let messages = [];
  if (name.value === '' || name.value == null || name.value === 'a') {
    messages.push('Name is required');
  }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    error.innerText = messages.join(', ')
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="errorMessage"> </div>

<form action="/" method="GET" id="formZ">
  <div id="form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" class="inputField" id="name">
    </div>
    <div id="submitArea">
      <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: amazing, thank you very much. I have taken the required fields out. So basically, by using the "required" in html, the browser stops any submission, therefore it couldn't be submitted incorrectly to show an error message? Yes sorry i did have those variables but forgot to show them.

Comment: @ChaliiiseR maybe you can leave the `required` and trigger a validation function every time the submit button is clicked with `onclick="someFunction()"`, that way, you can have the benefits of both worlds.

Comment: so a function for when its clicked, rather than submitted? interesting, yes i will definitely have a go at that. I spent 4 hours trying to figure this out yesterday, you have no idea how happy i am right now! thanks again.